# Automatic Update Class on windows 8

Tags: c#, .net, windows-8, windows-update

I'm using .NET 3.5 framework.

I'm using `Inerop.WUApiLib` to check/set windows update settings.

Everything works fine on windows 7 but on windows 8 it fails.

After a research I found that you can't set the time when "windows update" will run.
Instead, you should set the time for the [Automatic Maintenance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh848037%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and then "windows update" will run as part of the maintenance operations.

Is there a way to set the time for the Automatic Maintenance?

**EDIT:**

I found a task named "Task Scheduler" in the task scheduler.
apparently when setting the time for this task it would cause the automatic maintenance to start on that time.

the problem is that after the maintenance is finished or after restarting the computer the schedule time is reset back to its original value.

**DOUBLE EDIT:**

1. the reason why the schedule time is resetting every time is because there is another task "Maintenance Configurator" which is responsible  of resetting the time to the user requested time.
2. I found another task - "Manual Maintenance" which you can set at any time you want and the Maintenance will run at that time.

I still want to figure out a way to set the regular maintenance,so there won't be 2 tasks that doing the same thing, but at least now I can set the time for the Automatic Maintenance